# How to add bootstrap dropdown lists to buttons inside list elements

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list of `li` elements added to the page by `d3.append` function.
I'd like each `li` to have a button with dropdown list, showing some options.

I'm adding dropdowns with d3 like this:

```
var innerUl = li.append("ul")
    .attr("class","dropdown-menu");

innerUl.selectAll("li")
    .data(function(d) { return d.style_aliases; })
    .enter()
    .append("li").html(function(d) { return d; });
```

However, when dropdown button is clicked, nothing happens. But I can see an added dropdown `ul` in elements inspector.
The jsfiddle of what I'm trying to do is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mofoyoda/dcy4xb7j/1/

Please help me to reveal the dropdown for every button.

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere where you define what values are supposed to be in the dropdown.

Comment: @jonmrich it's in the last line in the fiddle code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem appears to be resolved by not placing the button in its own span

```
li.append("button")
    .attr("class", "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-layerstyle")
    .attr("data-toggle", "dropdown")
    .attr("aria-haspopup", "true")
    .attr("aria-expanded", "false")
    .html("Style: ") //default style name should be concatenated here
      .append("span")
        .attr("class","caret");
```

The button and the related dropdown list appear to need to be in the same parent element. The dropdown list is in the wrong location, but this should be a simple CSS issue to fix. Alternatively, ensuring the button and the dropdown list are within the `span` would probably have the same effect.

You can incidentally set multiple attr values in one statement

```
li.append("button")
    .attr({
       "class": "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-layerstyle",
       "data-toggle": "dropdown",
       "aria-haspopup": "true",
       "aria-expanded":"false"})
    .html("Style: ") //default style name should be concatenated here
      .append("span")
        .attr("class","caret");
```

Comment: Yes, place the button and its dropdown list in a div of class `btn-group` 
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns